# How to Fully Logout of Azure AD With OWIN and Redirect after?

Tags: asp.net, azure, model-view-controller, active-directory, owin

I have a MVC ASP.net Web Application that is using Azure AD To Login.  I have an action in my controller that is in charge of signing out that uses

```
   Request.GetOwinContext()
           .Authentication
           .SignOut(HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
            .Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes()
            .Select(o => o.AuthenticationType).ToArray());
```

This however leaves me stuck at the Microsoft "We Recommend you close your browser screen" and it never redirects anywhere. Then after if I try to login again it auto logs me in as if cookies are not clearing or it is retaining my login somehow.  How do I fully logout and then redirect afterwards?  If you logout of any Microsoft Office 365 product this is the behavior I am looking for.  It logs you out without retaining any info/cookies and then redirects you back to the Owin Login Page. Any help or insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is construct a sign out URI in your application and when the user clicks on the Logout link or button, you redirect your users to that URI.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={1}
```

Where {0} is your Tenant Id or the Azure AD name (Fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com) and {1} is the link to your application where a user will be redirected back after the sign out process is complete at Azure AD end.

Apart from that you have to clear the cookies at application front.

In this way you can redirect user to custom page and also you can start the process from beginning.

Similar thread for [reference](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/127).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. How exactly would I go about manually clearing said cookies though?